# Initialize documentReference through string fails

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a method that returns a string that I know for sure points to a document. When using that string as follow:

```
const docRef = "users/uid/data/online"
const dbPath = db.doc(docRef)
console.log(dbPath.path)
return dbPath.set({"test" : 1})
```

It fails:

[image]

If I use db.collection("users").doc(uid)...... it works. How can I create a document reference through a string in typescript?

It should work according to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#references

edit: This is my class:

```
export enum UserCollection {
    online = "online",
    private = "private",
    server = "server"
}

export enum UserDocument { 
    online = "online",
    private = "private",
    server = "server"
}

class ManagerPath { 

    pathToUser = "users/"

    getPathToUser(uid: string, userCollection: UserCollection, userDocument: UserDocument): string { 
        return this.pathToUser + "/" + uid + "/" + userCollection + "/" + userDocument;
    }

}

export const managerPath = new ManagerPath();
```

And this is how I retrieve a path:

```
exports.initializeNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const test = managerPath.getPathToUser(user.uid, UserCollection.online, UserDocument.online);
    console.log(test)
    const dbPath = db.doc(test)
    return dbPath.set({"dateCreation" : Date.now()}) //fails
})
```

Comment: Where are you getting the path string from? How are you creating it?  Is it a field in an existing document?  It would be useful to know where you are getting the variables from that are required to build the string.

Comment: @JasonBerryman I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to create a document in the `/users` collection, as well as the `online` sub-collection.  Otherwise, you'll end up with an orphaned collection.  I've added some code to do this as a batch.

There are many other details that you can get from the `user` event, which you could save in the document, such as email, name, photoURL, etc.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it should do what you need.

```
exports.initializeNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const userRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userOnlineRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}/online/online`);
    const dateCreation = user.metadata.creationTime;

    let batch = db.batch();
    batch.create(userRef, {dateCreation})
    batch.create(userOnlineRef, {dateCreation})
    return batch.commit();
})
```

*Requires >= 1.0.0 of the Functions SDK*

### Fixing your code

You have declared your `pathToUser` as `"users/"` then added another `/`.  You can fix this by modifying the following line

```
return this.pathToUser + "/" + uid + "/" + userCollection + "/" + userDocument;
```

to

```
return this.pathToUser + uid + "/" + userCollection + "/" + userDocument;
```

or

```
pathToUser = 'users'; // The trailing / has been removed

return `${this.pathToUser}/${uid}/${userCollection}/${userDocument}`;
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I do not really see how this answers my question. I want to create a document reference through a string, without using ".collection()". The docs say it is possible, but I get an error. My goal is to retrieve paths from ManagerPath class, and than update the given path, which is a document reference.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the necessity for the `collection` property.  However, I also see that you have 2 x `/` in your code.  I'll add this to my answer, also.

Comment: I added a fix to your code, as well as my recommended code for using batches